# I created a jQuery slideshow but it keeps repeating the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

as you can see in the code provided below, I have created a simple jQuery slideshow that runs automatically. But I have ran into a little problem that I cant seem to figure out. When the slideshow runs it goes perfectly, but once it gets to the last image then it just keeps on repeating! How can I prevent this from happening?? The code is below and there is also a link to the images. THANKS!:) P.S- I'm using older jQuery versions because of deprecated functions!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Home
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="body" onload="Slider()">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bg">
        <div class="mainHeader">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="topArea">
          <div class="topAInfo">
            <h2>Here is just a simple title</h2>
            <p>This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middleArea">
          <div class="slider">
            <img id="1" src="slide1.jpg" border="0" alt="slide1" width="800px" height="350px">
            <img id="2" src="slide2.jpg" border="0" alt="slide2" width="800px" height="350px"> 
            <img id="3" src="slide3.jpg" border="0" alt="slide3" width="800px" height="350px">
          </div>
          <div class="middleAInfo">
            <h3>Welcome to</h3>
            <p>A dummy website!!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="latestNews">
            <hr>
            <h2>Latest News</h2>
            <div class="post">
              <p class="date">March 28, 2015</p>
              <p>New advanced update with double speed and a whole bunch of cool new st.. <a href="#">more&gt;&gt;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
              <p class="date">March 28, 2015</p>
              <p>New advanced update with double speed and a whole bunch of cool new st.. <a href="#">more&gt;&gt;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="newsLetter">
              <div class="newsLInfo">
                <h3>Newsletter sign-up</h3>
                <hr>
                <p>If you would like to sign up for our free NewsLetter please enter your email below</p>
                <a href="#">Unsubscribe</a>
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="textBox" class="textBox" style="width:200px; height:20px;">
              <div class="button1">Submit</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--https://www.freelancer.com/jobs/php/PSD-HTML-page-only-page/-->
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
@font-face {
    font-family: SketchFont;
    src: url(Fonts/Sketch_Block.ttf);
}
body{
    background:#ebebeb;
    width:80%;
    height:1300px;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
}
.mainHeader nav{
    width:95%;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    left:30px;
    top:60px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* Standard syntax */
    /*margin: 100px 50px 0 150px;*/
}
.mainHeader nav ul{

}
.mainHeader nav ul li{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #ADADA8;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-top:none;
    border-left:none;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li.last{
    border-right:none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    /*margin:10px Use to replace paddings right/left but causes hovedr errors*/
    font-family:Arial;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a.active{
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a:hover{
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
.topArea{
    width:95%;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    left:30px;
    top:10px;
    /*margin: -50px 50px 0 150px;*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* Standard syntax */
}
.topArea .topAInfo{
    margin:20px;
    padding-top:60px;
    width:60%;
    margin:50px;
    font-family:;
}
.topArea .topAInfo h2{
    font-family:SketchFont;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.topArea .topAInfo p{
    line-height:25px;
    font-family:cursive;
    font-size:15px;
}
.bg{
    width:100%;
    height:1200px;
    position:relative;
    left:10%;
    background:linear-gradient(blue, white, white, blue); /* Standard syntax */
    /*background-image:url(bg2.jpg);*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.middleArea{
    background:linear-gradient(white, white, #55C4E9); /* Standard syntax */;
    height:600px;
    width:95%;
    position:relative;
    left:30px;
    top:10px;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo {
    padding:30px 0 0 30px;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo p{
    color:#49CBF0;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:400;
}
.middleArea .latestNews {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background:#0099cc;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:-60px;
    border:1px solid #D6D8D8;
}
.middleArea .latestNews hr{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    color:black;
    width:90%;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews h2{
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color:white;
}
.middleArea .latestNews p.date{
    color:white;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews p{
    color:white;
    font-size:13px;
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    width:225px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews a{
    color:blue;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter{
    background:white;
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    border:1px solid #D6D8D8;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter .textBox{
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    left:25px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter .button1{
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
    background:#1768ED;
    padding:3px 10px 2px 10px;
    border-radius:7px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    position:relative;
    top:45px;
    left:155px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter .button1:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter h3{
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:10px;
    color:#21AFEA;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter hr{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    color:#21AFEA;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter p{
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    color:#21AFEA;
    font-size:15px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter a{
    position:relative;
    top:90px;
    left:30px;
}
.slider{
    width:800px;
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:30px auto;
    background-image:url(loading.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}
.slider img{
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function Slider(){
    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 500);
    var sc = 3;
    var count = 2;

    setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider #"+count).show("slide", {direction:'right'}, 500);
        $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 500);

        if(count == sc){
            count == 1;
        }else{
            count = count + 1;
        }
    },6500);
}
```

Images:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8cxqlfp7i46066/slides.zip?dl=0

Comment: possible duplicate of [I made a jquery slide show but it dosent work right, what do i do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326628/i-made-a-jquery-slide-show-but-it-dosent-work-right-what-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you mistake was in the if-statement.

```
if(count == sc){
    count == 1;
}else{
    count = count + 1;
}
```

You wrote

```
count == 1;
```

instead of

```
count = 1;
```

Common mistake, made it a lot by myself. Hard to track.

This is how your script should look like:

```
function Slider(){
    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 100);
    $(".slider #1").delay(1000).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 100);
    sc = 3;
    count = 2;

    setInterval(function(){

        $(".slider #"+count).show("slide", {direction:'right'}, 100);
        $(".slider #"+count).delay(1000).hide("slide", {direction:'left'},    100);

        if(count == sc){
            count = 1;
        }else{
            count++;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

You should start to use you console (nearly all modern browser have one, enable it by pressing F12 (FireFox/Chrome))

Answer (score 0):

How about passing next slide as a parameter to the function?

```
    function Slider(i){
        $(".slider #"+i).show("fade", 500);
        $(".slider #"+i).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 500);
        var sc = 3;
        var netxslide=i+1;
        if (nextslide==sc+1){nextslide=1}

        setInterval(function(){Slider(nextslide)},6500);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   if(count == sc){
        count == 1;
    }else{
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Your first count == 1; should be count = 1;

You're not setting the variable, only calculating TRUE.

Replace with:

```
   if(count == sc){
        count = 1;
    }else{
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It was answered around the same time as the accepted answer, and is more or less the same. Looks like my constructive comments on another users answer (which didn't even remotely answer the question, and has since been removed) caused them to downvote in retaliation.